# Data not saving in session variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

The data is not storing in session everything is working fine the login system all things but the Data like username user pass and user Id should be saved in session but it's not I know it because if it was saving when you login successfully it should show welcome {username}.

Proceed to forums the main page but it is not showing username it was showing before but I got to problems and when all problems fixed this error came out.

Code:

```
<style>
<?php include 'signin.css'; ?>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="signup.js"></script>
<?php
//signin.php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';
 
//first, check if the user is already signed in. If that is the case, there is no need to display this page
if(isset($_SESSION['signed_in']) && $_SESSION['signed_in'] == true)
{
    echo 'You are already signed in, you can <a href="signout.php">sign out</a> if you want.';
}
else
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    {
        /*the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
          note that the action="" will cause the form to post to the same page it is on */
        echo '<form action="" method="post"  >
<div class="all" >
<div class="container" >
<div class="first" >
<h2>SIGN IN</h2>
</div>
<div class="user" >
<input class="use"  type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="user_name" required>
</div>
<div class="userimg" >
<img  src="user.png" style="height:2em;width:2em;" >
</div>
<div class="pass" >
<input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"  name="user_pass" minlength="8" required  >
<img src="lock.png" >
</div>
<div class="show">
<img src="visible.png" id="visible" class="visible" onclick="myFunction()">
<img src="invisible.png" id="invisible"  class="invisible" onclick="mynot()" >
</div>
<div class="check" >
<input type="checkbox" required >
</div>
<div class="box" >
<p>I accept all <a href="#" >terms</a> and <a href="#" >privacy</a>.</p>
</div>
<div class="submit" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="submit()" value="Sign in">
</div>
<div class="close" >
<input type="button" value="Back"  >
</div>
<div class="log" >
dont have an account? <a href="#" >Login</a>
</div>
<div class="organic" >
<img src="logo.png" class="organicpe" >
</div>
<div>
<h2 class="back" ><a href="#" >Go Back</a></h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>';
    }
    else
    {
        /* so, the form has been posted, we'll process the data in three steps:
            1.  Check the data
            2.  Let the user refill the wrong fields (if necessary)
            3.  Verify if the data is correct and return the correct response
        */
        $errors = array(); /* declare the array for later use */
         
        if(!isset($_POST['user_name']))
        {
            $errors[] = 'The username field must not be empty.';
        }
         
        if(!isset($_POST['user_pass']))
        {
            $errors[] = 'The password field must not be empty.';
        }
         
        if(!empty($errors)) /*check for an empty array, if there are errors, they're in this array (note the ! operator)*/
        {
            echo 'Uh-oh.. a couple of fields are not filled in correctly..';
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($errors as $key => $value) /* walk through the array so all the errors get displayed */
            {
                echo '<li>' . $value . '</li>'; /* this generates a nice error list */
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        else
        {
            //the form has been posted without errors, so save it
            //notice the use of mysql_real_escape_string, keep everything safe!
            //also notice the sha1 function which hashes the password
            $sql = "SELECT 
                        user_id,
                        user_name,
                        user_level
                    FROM
                        Users
                    WHERE
                        user_name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "'
                    AND
                        user_pass = '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "'";
          
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            if(!$result)
            {
                //something went wrong, display the error
                echo 'Something went wrong while signing in. Please try again later.';
                //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
            }
            else
            {
                //the query was successfully executed, there are 2 possibilities
                //1. the query returned data, the user can be signed in
                //2. the query returned an empty result set, the credentials were wrong
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
                {
                    echo 'You have supplied a wrong user/password combination. Please try again.';
                }
                else
                {
                    while ($row = $result -> fetch_row()) 
                    session_start();
                    //set the $_SESSION['signed_in'] variable to TRUE
                    $_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;
                     
                    //we also put the user_id and user_name values in the $_SESSION, so we can use it at various pages
                
                    {
                        $_SESSION['user_id']    = $row['user_id'];
                        $_SESSION['user_name']  = $row['user_name'];
                        $_SESSION['user_level'] = $row['user_level'];
                    }
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//set the $_SESSION['signed_in'] variable to TRUE
$_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;                  
//we also put the user_id and user_name values in the $_SESSION, so we can use it at various pages
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name']; 
}
                     }
                    echo '<h3>Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '. <a href="index.php">Proceed to the forum overview</a>.</h1>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Comment: are you calling `session_start()` in any of those included files?

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text or using MD5/SHA1!** Only store password hashes created using PHP's [`password_hash()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), which you can then verify using [`password_verify()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Take a look at this post: [How to use password_hash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30279321/1839439) and learn more about [bcrypt & password hashing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/1839439)

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` does not exist

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: The gentleman I M just using this file I haven't gone yo other I want it to save because it show the username here too

Answer (score 0):

You need to start every php file use session with

```
session_start();
```

Comment: Bro I am using thus file just and I have session start